# show/hide search Div angular UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm using angular UI buttons to make users select search criteria when user select buttons Patient or id it will show searchByText div if select date it will hide searchByText and show SearchBydateRange. my problem my is the angular show and hide is not working. and I use this codepen as example 
http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/iBhoJ

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div id="searchByText" class="form-group form-group-search" ng-hide=" searchOption == 'date'">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="search">Enter Search</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Enter {{searchOption}} ..." data-ng-model="searchText">
                </div>
                <div id="SearchBydateRange" class="form-group form-group-search col-md-4" data-ng-show=" searchOption  == 'date' ">
                    <label class=" sr-only" for="search">
                        Enter Search
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2" id="search" placeholder="From Date" data-ng-model="fromDate">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2" id="search" placeholder="To Date" data-ng-model="toDate">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" data-ng-hide="userIsManager">

                    <label class="btn btn-searchsel" ng-model="searchOption" btn-radio="'patient'">Patient</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-searchsel" ng-model="searchOption" btn-radio="'id'">ID</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-searchsel" ng-model="searchOption" btn-radio="'Date'" va>Date</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-search full-width" data-ng-click="doSearch()">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when user select date is not show from/to search  and  hide  search text input

Comment: so you do not want your searchbar to hide? or do you want it to?

Comment: I have two search divs one is text and other one date pikers FromDate to date"date range " if the user click  date button will hide search by text div and show date range search ?

Comment: use an ng-show or ng-hide?

Comment: I'm using it  but it is not working ? see the update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the button part to this: (label or radio does not matter, but the important part is ng-click)

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" data-ng-hide="userIsManager">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="searchOption" value="patient" ng-click="searchOption = 'patient'">Patient</label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="searchOption" value="id" ng-click="searchOption = 'id'">ID</label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="searchOption" value="Date" ng-click="searchOption = 'date'">Date</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then for your search div's:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
            <div id="searchByText" class="form-group form-group-search" ng-hide=" searchOption == 'date'">
                <label class="sr-only" for="search">Enter Search</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Enter {{searchOption}} ..." ng-model="searchText">
            </div>
            <div id="SearchBydateRange" class="form-group form-group-search col-md-4" ng-show=" searchOption  == 'date' ">
                <label class=" sr-only" for="search">
                    Enter Search
                </label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control col-md-2" id="search" placeholder="From Date" ng-model="fromDate">
                <input type="date" class="form-control col-md-2" id="search" placeholder="To Date" ng-model="toDate">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: did you see angular UI directive buttons  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons ?